# onclick function opening two links when I only want one link to open

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, onclick

In my code I only want the Google link to open in a new tab, but when I click on the button for the Google link (which does open in a new tab), the original tab goes to the stackoverflow page (even though it was not clicked). I don't want the button of the stackoverflow button to be clicked and opened when the user only clicked the google one, I want it to stay on my homepage. Any ideas why the onclick is triggering both URLs?

Here is my code snippet:

```html
<div class="btns-A">
  <div><a href="https://google.com" class="btn-A" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Go to Google</a></div>

  <div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn-A">Go to Stack</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, because you are opening the link once with a `<a>` link and a second time with some overkill Javascript. The code is explicit

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal action of clicking on the link.

Comment: I just updated the code and still having the issue. Why is the stack one opening too?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `document.getElementById(x).addEventListener('click', function() {...});` instead of a `onclick` event;
2. If you use `<a>` with a href tag you do not need a second JS script to run (`<a>` opens the link just fine (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Why doesn't a simple target blank work in this situation? or ```<div class="btns-A">
  <div><a href="https://google.com" class="btn-A" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Go to Google</a></div>

  <div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn-A">Go to Stack</a></div>
</div>```

Comment: Why do you want to have the same event fire as a `<a>` AND as a `onclick`?

Comment: I only want the first link to open in a new tab, but target blank did not work and when I apply an onclick it is causing the second URL to load which I don't want. I think I'm just making a mess of it.

Comment: Okay, then I suggest you could do something like this: `documet.getElementById(yourLinkId).addEventListener('click', function() {window.location.href = "http://www.YourWebPage.com";}`; this also makes your href in `<a>` obsolete

Comment: Also take a look at this article to learn more about `taget='_blank'`: https://medium.com/sedeo/how-to-fix-target-blank-a-security-and-performance-issue-in-web-pages-2118eba1ce2f

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your question you can just use

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Link to Google</a>
```

You can find some documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) 

Your Javascript is not necessary here.

Comment: The target="_blank" was not working in my code for some reason.

Comment: @Anna in the code provided it works, but if you are working inside another tag such as iframe it may cause problems.